# SDL_Mixer undefined reference to Mix_OpenAudio

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, sdl-2

I've been working on a project lately which uses SDL2. For audio, I want to use the SDL_Mixer library, and I've downloaded the necessary libaries as I did with SDL_ttf and SDL_image. They are downloaded at C:/dev. I'm compiling with CMake and MinGW 32bit. When builing the project, this error is thrown:

```
GameManager.cpp:25: undefined reference to `Mix_OpenAudio'
```

The line it throws an error at is:

```
if (Mix_OpenAudio( 44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048 ) < 0)
    return -1;
```

My CMake looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(PLOpenSource VERSION 0.1.0)

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/dev/sdl2/SDL2-2.0.20/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2;C:/dev/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2;C:/dev/SDL2_ttf-2.0.18/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2;C:/dev/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2")
set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "C:/dev/sdl2/SDL2-2.0.20/i686-w64-mingw32/lib;C:/dev/SDL2_image-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/lib;C:/dev/SDL2_ttf-2.0.18/i686-w64-mingw32/lib;C:/dev/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/i686-w64-mingw32/lib")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/output)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(PLOpenSource main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(k4sdl)
add_subdirectory(game)
target_link_libraries(PLOpenSource SDL2 SDL2_image SDL2_ttf)
```

What could be the cause of this error? It didn't happen when builing only with SDL_ttf and SDL_image.

Comment: You are missing SDL2_mixer in link libraries.

Comment: They're at the end of the variable SDL2_LIBRARIES (`C:/dev/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/i686-w64-mingw32/lib`) which I link with link_directories.

Comment: OH I SEE IT NOW SORRY SORRY SORRY